# Change text "My Basket" in woocommerce artificer theme

Tags: plugins, headers, buttons

I am working with the woocommerce artificer theme and there is a place in the header where it says "My Basket" and then the amount that is in your cart.
[image]
I would like to change the text to say "My Cart".  I have looked around.  I even found a post on here where the poster shows where the files come from the post can be found here: [Change My Basket text in the header of WooCommerce Artificer theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/109750/41346)

I went into the theme-woocommerce file that they talk about and changed the text, although it did not change on the page.  I went to the function woocommerce_cart_link() and I deleted everything in the function except:
`<a href=""  class="cart-button "> </a>`
And the stupid My Basket thing still came up.  I delete the class="cart-button " and the button disappears.  Is there a hook on the class or how can I find the source so I can get this working?  I would like to get the "My Basket" text to say "My Cart" and eventually I will try and change that thing to the left that looks like a cardboard box.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, `woocommerce_cart_link()` is added to the site just before the menu by the `artificer_header_cart_link()` function, which is pluggable, meaning you *could* change that function to call a function that duplicates `woocommere_cart_link()` but with the text changed.

However, I think the easiest thing to do is to tap into the [`gettext filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) which kicks in for every translatable string.... and all of Woo's themes are fully translatable.

This will change any "My Basket:" string anywhere in the theme to say "My Cart:"

```
function wpa_109750_change_text( $translated_text, $text, $domain ){
    if( $domain == 'woothemes' && $translated_text == 'My Basket:' )
        $translated_text = 'My Cart:';

    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpa_109750_change_text', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: You are awesome